# Re-using Text Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Overview:

I am making a small quiz where a question is posted at the top (pulled from an ajax get) and you can answer in the text area. Upon clicking the next button I'd like for it to post the input to my MongoDB, then display an empty text area with a new question at the top, without loading a new page. Likewise, if you hit previous I'd like for the previous question to be displayed as well as the answer in the text area.

I'm thinking I can maybe store the answers with cookies in between next/previous but I am mainly unsure of that and how I can display a blank area without loading a new page (I am not familiar with Angular).

### HTML:

```
       <form name="answers" method="post">
        <textarea rows="30" cols="150" id="editor"></textarea>

             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='previous'>Previous</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='next'>Next</button>

        </div>

     </form>
```

Submit

### AJAX POST:

```
 $( "#next" ).click(function() {
        var info = $('#editor').val()
        $.ajax({        
            url: "/tests/" + authCode,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {authCode: authCode}, {info: info},
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            complete: function() {
              //called when complete
              console.log('process complete');
            },

            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log('process sucess');
           },

            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
              console.log('process error');
            },
        });
```

Comment: What problem, exactly, are you having with this?

Comment: Upon clicking next, the text area does not display as blank again. I would also like to click previous and have it display whatever was typed in before.

Comment: You need to empty the textarea when it's been posted, using `$('#editor').val("")`.  The previous button needs to call a different server method to get the previous question and the answer that was posted.

Comment: @Archer thanks this is what i was looking for!

Comment: Is there any unique id in URL where you can get the value?